# Django login script constantly returning invalid request

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I hope someone can help.

I'm new to Django and have been following tutorials to make a login script. I've created a script that allows a user to login with a **users** table in postgres from a HTML form. The login script always returns "Invalid User" though the users credentials are correct. I've followed many troubleshooting guides and I'm now at the end of my tether, it's really frustrating. Please see my code below for the different sections. Any help would be appreciated

```
Account\Views.py 

def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("home")

    destination = get_redirect_if_exists(request)
    print("destination: " + str(destination))

    if request.POST:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if destination:
                    return redirect(destination)
                return redirect("home")

    else:
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    return render(request, "account/login.html", context)


def get_redirect_if_exists(request):
    redirect = None
    if request.GET:
        if request.GET.get("next"):
            redirect = str(request.GET.get("next"))
    return redirect
```

```
Account\forms.py 
class AccountAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'password')

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login")
```

```
urls.py

from account.views import(
    register_view,
    login_view,
    logout_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name='home'),
    path('register/', register_view, name='register'),
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
]
```

```
Login Form

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card card-signin">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-signin" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

                <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

                {% for field in login_form %}
                <p>
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                </p>
                {% endfor %}
                {% if login_form.non_field_errors %}
                <div style="color: red">
                <p>{{login_form.non_field_errors}}</p>
                </div>

                {% endif %}

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </form>

                <div class="d-flex flex-column my-4">
                    <a class="m-auto" href="#">Reset password</a>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
Account\model.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.conf import settings



class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

def get_profile_image_filepath(self, filename):
    return 'profile_images/' + str(self.pk) + '/profile_image.png'

def get_default_profile_image():
    return "images/logo_1080_1080.png"

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissions
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```